# How to make the click of 1 button change the .innerhtml of multiple things?

Tags: javascript, html, events, mouseclick-event

I'm new to javascript and programming and I'm attempting to make a program for my workouts. I want to be able to input the amount of sets, reps, and weight I lifted and then have the program output integers that are incrementally more challenging for my next workout. At the bottom I'm trying to get the enter button to change the .innerHTML of two different elements. Is this even possible?

`

```
var userMovement1 = document.getElementById("movement-1").value;
var userSet1 = document.getElementById("set-user-1").value;
var userReps1 = document.getElementById("reps-user-1").value;
var userWeight1 = document.getElementById("weight-user-1").value;
var enterButton = document.getElementById("enter-button");

//Function will calculate the reps for the next workout

function calculateFutureReps(performedReps) {

var futureReps = performedReps;

if (performedReps < 12) {

    return futureReps += 2; 

} else if (performedReps >= 12) {

    return futureReps = 6;
}
 }

 //Function will calculate the weight for the next workout

function calculateFutureWeight(performedWeight) {

var futureWeight = performedWeight
if (performedWeight < 12) {

    return futureWeight; 

} else if (performedWeight >= 12) {

    return futureWeight += 10;
}
 }

 //Getting the value of the functions and storing them in a variable

var newReps = calculateFutureReps(userReps1).value;
var newWeight = calculateFutureReps(userWeight1).value;

//Making that variable show up on the DOM

enterButton.onclick() = document.getElementById("reps-next-1").innerHTML = newReps;
enterButton.onclick() = document.getElementById("weight-next-1").innerHTML = newWeight;`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to handle the click and is a function to do whatever you want in there.

```js
enterButton.addEventHandler('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("reps-next-1").innerHTML = newReps;
  document.getElementById("weight-next-1").innerHTML = newWeight;
});
`
```